# Error while storing records from Access field in array

Tags: sql, arrays, database, ms-access, vba

**Situation :**

I have this code which stores all the records from the field *Shipment ID* in an array called *arrayShipmentID*.

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ShipmentIDSQL As String
Dim arrayShipmentID() As Variant

connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "P:\PathToTheAccessDatabase\" & "NewVersion.accdb" & ";"
conn.ConnectionString = connStr
conn.Open

' Store Shipment IDs
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    ShipmentIDSQL = "SELECT [Shipment ID] FROM 12Dec"
    rs.Open ShipmentIDSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        arrayShipmentID = rs.GetRows
    End If
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrayShipmentID, 2)
        Debug.Print arrayShipmentID(0, i)
    Next i
    Set rs = Nothing
```

In order to make sure it works I `Debug.Print` each element of the array.

**Issue :**

This code WORKS most of the time, but for some reason, sometimes I get as a value 'subscript out of range' (instead of 181 in my case) for  `MsgBox UBound(arrayShipmentID, 2)` and of course in that case Debug.Print doesn't display anything in the Immediate Window.

Any ideas where could this come from ?

Answer (score 0):

With DAO recordsets you often have to find the recordcount to retrieve all records. That might be the case for ADO as well:

```
RecordCount = ' Obtain true count of records.
arrayShipmentID = rs.GetRows(RecordCount)
```

Also, I normally declare the variable as a simple Variant:

```
Dim arrayShipmentID As Variant
```